# How to extract specific color from Project Tango point cloud data?

Tags: java, android, blender, google-project-tango, point-clouds

I wanted to use Tango's RGB camera along with its Depth data to create a specific point cloud involving only one color, but I'm not sure how to approach this.

What i want to do is ultimately re-construct an object in blender based on it's XYZ value and the way I'm trying to extract this object from its background is based on color because it doesn't have any depth on it's own. Like a drawing on a 3D object.

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend to check the examples in the C api of tango. It should be possible to do it all in java but the example in c called cpp_rgb_depth_sync_example should give you several ideas
Check the code in https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c

This example puts the information of the pointcloud in the color image... you just want to do the inverse!

For each point cloud:
- Gather the previous color image
- Using the camera intrinsics (see the example above), you can link each point of the point cloud with a voxel in the image.
- Once you have the color for each point you can remove the points you are not interested in.

One thing to remind is that the color image is in a yuv format (you might want to convert it in RBG).

I hope this will help.

Comment: Can you just give a psuedocode of "how to remove the points you are not interested in" ? Im able to get proper colour segmentation , Lets say i want to include only the point below colorindex 72 , what can be an approach towards it ?